# open with ... causes one program to appear multiple times

Tags: linux-mint, open-files, okular

I have a: fresh installation of Linux mint 20 cinnamon a week ago (luv it)
and i have 3d ays ago installed okular for pdfs.

*My Problem:* when i want to open a file, that is unknown to the system with `open with...`
then i get the weird behavior of many okular's to choose from. Please see picture below:  [image: Many Okulars popping up]

I installed okular from the standard 'Software Manager' it is version 4:19.12.3-2ubuntu1. Found out it is a KDE Graphic Module. And I looked up odd behavior of `open with...`

*My question*: How can I only show one okular in the choose Program tray of `open with...` ?

*I want*:

> Okular to appear only once in the "Open with..."- list.

I think the okular options are getting more (kind of funny).
 Thanks in advance

Comment: is the question understandable?

Comment: i still did not figure out, why this happens...

Comment: i did deinstall the programm because it multiplicated so much... any thing would be helpful

Comment: same problem here, on arch linux. Does anyone know where it generates the "Open With..." list from?

Comment: please upvote the question, it was down voted for not beeing understandable.
I dont know the reason and it only happens with okular. so i guess it is something okular specific? 
I have to add i havent tried for a long time, but now it works under linux mint:
5.4.0-104-generic #118-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 2 19:02:41 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
okular version 21.12.1
maybe it is fixed?

Comment: yes good point. I've now upvoted the question. So I still haven't solved this, but I think it is something to do with the myriad of okular desktop files in `/usr/share/applications`. Inspecting those files, they each appear to handle a different MIME type, so it's unclear why okular is appearing lots of times. But after moving all of these files out of that directory, leaving only `okularApplication_pdf.desktop` I can confirm okular now only appears once in the 'Open With' list (oddly, it doesn't seem to matter that I'm not even trying to open a PDF).

Comment: That is a good answer! Awesome. I think, I can close the case with that work around, please provide it as an answer.
for me it works now under linux mint since updates. but i guess it doesnt work every where.